# How to add a color background in status bar icon

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I want to add a color background **behind the text** in status bar icon like in a screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried to subclass NSView (to set the color in drawRect) and assign it to NSStatusItem's view property:

`statusItem.view = newView`

But it becomes not clickable. Maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of creating the image of an NSStatusItem object with NSImage?

Comment: Do you mean like this `statusItem.image = img`? Is there a way to add text label on the foreground?

Comment: Basically if i do this `statusItem.image = img
  statusItem.title = "lorem ipsum"`, it puts text next to an image, not on the foreground

Comment: Draw a string on NSImage.